# Updating a single field in a record with Haskell @

Tags: haskell

I need to update one field of a very large default record.

As the default may change I don't want to rebuild the entire record manually.

Now I have come across the following way of doing this, but I am not sure how it works:

```
unaggregate :: MyResult -> MyResult
unaggregate calc@MyResult{..} = calc{ the_defaults = the_override
                                         `mappend` the_defaults }
  where
    the_override = create ("aggregation" := False)
```

I have tried searching for 'Haskell @ operator' in Google but it does not return immediately useful information.

I saw somewhere `calc@MyResult{..}`  does pattern matching on variables but I don't see what variable `calc` does for the  `MyResult` record...

Also I have looked up `mappend` (and Monoids) and I am not sure how these work either...

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@` symbol is called an "as-pattern". In the example above, you can use `calc` to mean the whole record. Usually you'd use it like this: `calc@(MyResult someResult)` -- so you can have both the whole thing and the pieces that you're matching. You can do the same thing with lists (`myList@(myHead:myTail)`) or tuples (`myTuple@(myFst, mySnd)`. It's pretty handy!

`MyResult{..}` uses [RecordWildcards](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-04-record-wildcards.html). Which is a neat extension! BUT  RecordWildcards doesn't help you update just one field of a record.

You can do this instead: `calc { theFieldYouWantToUpdate = somethingNew }`.

Comment: Like you said above, it's an operation on monoids. Monoids are anything that can a) be empty and b) be "added" together. So, lists are monoids. You can have an empty list (`[]`) and you can add lists together (`mappend [1] [2] == [1,2]`). Maybes and maps and text and many other things ares also monoids, so you can `mappend` those too.